# User registration with mandatory Mobile Number

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm creating an app that contains a registration form. If I make mobile number field mandatory then will there be any problem while uploading the app on the App Store or will there be any chances of app rejection? If yes, please explain why.

Comment: There won't be any issues, you can add it.

Comment: It's based on category selection, In which category, you are going to upload app.
For Ex:- Regi. form ask about Email Id and you upload app in education category thn Apple will reject.

Comment: Mine is in travel category. Is it fine?

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah Hi - Can you please explain how category will matter for user's personal data collection policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask for any field mandatory. Then make sure that you are using that value in you app. If you are using that value for any purpose. Then there is no issue with apple Approval.

In my one of the app I have used mobile number in the same way you said(means for login of the user) that app get approved. But in another app where I get user's mobile number but not used any where in the app then that app get rejected. And I have to make that field as an optional.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

“Apple’s App Store Review Guidelines” clearly mentions that iOS apps that transmit personal information without consent and proper notification to users on how the information is used and where it will used will be rejected.

17. Privacy

17.1 Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user’s prior permission and providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used

17.2 Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected

17.3 Apps may ask for date of birth (or use other age-gating mechanisms) only for the purpose of complying with applicable children’s privacy statutes, but must include some useful functionality or entertainment value regardless of the user’s age

17.4 Apps that collect, transmit, or have the capability to share personal information (e.g. name, address, email, location, photos, videos, drawings, the ability to chat, other personal data, or persistent identifiers used in combination with any of the above) from a minor must comply with applicable children’s privacy statutes, and must include a privacy policy

17.5 Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be rejected